# when i using Picasso in customadapter for listview image, when scroll down and back previous place listview, my image mix other position items

Tags: java, android, adapter, custom-adapter

When using the Picasso library for download image and printing in imageview in listview, I used BaseAdapter for listview image. When I scroll down and back previous place listview, my image mix other position items listview

my adapter code :

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
final ViewHolder holder;
if (view == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_items, null);


    holder.NoeMelk = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TxtNoeMelk);
    holder.Imgmelk = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Imgmelk);

    view.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}
// Set the results into TextViews

holder.Code.setText(worldParametrs.get(position).getId());

if (!worldParametrs.get(position).getPic1().equals("") ) {
    String picurl1 = "http://ansari-rs.ir/public/image/home/" + worldParametrs.get(position).getId() + "/" + worldParametrs.get(position).getPic1();

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(picurl1).resize(80, 110).into(holder.Imgmelk);
    Log.e("FOG", "http://ansari-rs.ir/public/image/home/" + worldParametrs.get(position).getId() + "/" + worldParametrs.get(position).getPic1());
    picurl1 = "";

}

return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add else for

```
if (!worldParametrs.get(position).getPic1().equals("") ) {
   //your code
} else {
    holder.Imgmelk.setDrawable(null)
}
```